# Cannot get Angular Material flex to work for layout

Tags: jquery, html, css, angularjs, angular-material

I have an Angular module which I refer in the index.html. The template file for the module is as follows:

```
<div id="{{$ctrl.link}}" class="container-fluid">
 <div layout="row">
  <div flex layout="row" layout-fill style="height:100%;">
   <div flex="40">
    <img src="{{$ctrl.image}}" height="600px"></img>
   </div>
   <div flex="40">
      Other Flex part
   </div>
   <div flex="20">
   </div>
  </div>
 </div>
</div>
```

The 2 divs should stack up in rows like -> div | div | div .However the divs just stack up in column.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your code doesn't seem to have any issues in HTML ( besides `img` being a self closing tag)

Although I simplified your code a bit.

[**CODEPEN**](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/wJdyPm)

```js
angular.module('myApp', ['ngMaterial'])
```

```html
<body ng-app="myApp">
  <div id="{{$ctrl.link}}" class="container-fluid">
    <div layout="row">
      <div flex layout="row">
        <div flex="40">
          <img src="//placehold.it/200" />
        </div>
        <div flex="40">
          Other Flex part
        </div>
        <div flex="20">hey
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</body>
```

P.S. - Did you use `ngMaterial` in your `angular.module`?

Comment: Used ngMaterial in the module

Comment: Yes I have. I opened the my code and checked carefully. I had added a width element for body which scrolled it out of sight. I fixed the issue by changing the width element.

Answer (score 0):

I haven't used Angular Material before, but after taking a quick look at the [docs](https://material.angularjs.org/latest/layout/introduction), it seems like this should work:

```
<div id="{{$ctrl.link}}" class="container-fluid">
  <div layout="row">
    <div flex="40">
      <img src="{{$ctrl.image}}" height="600px">
    </div>
    <div flex="40">
      Other Flex part
    </div>
    <div flex="20">
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

I think the problem was that you are nesting a row inside of a row which causes only one column to render in the parent row since that is its only child.

```
<div layout="row">
  <div flex layout="row" layout-fill style="height:100%;">
```

**Note:**

I'm not sure where to use `layout-fill`.  Play around with it either on the `row` itself or on the `columns` you want to fill.

Also, this is invalid html: `<img src="{{$ctrl.image}}" height="600px"></img>` (`<img>` tags are self closing).

Comment: I have used the code you used from the [link](https://material.angularjs.org/latest/layout/children) . But it is still not creating the necessary divs.

Comment: @SourajyotiBose, I did not copy and paste code from the docs.  Have you tried the code I've included above?

Comment: I did and it was still not working. And I did not mean you to insinuate that you have copied. I wanted to imply that the code is almost the same. Thanks for the suggestion and sorry if I offended you.